# Decimation with CMSIS FIR coefficients seems incorrect

Tags: embedded, signal-processing, cmsis

I am using an OEM ADC IC which has minimum sampling rate of `4000Hz`. I want to send the captured data over custom made existing solution whose parameters aren't intended to change.

Since the sampling rate of ADC is 4000Hz, I want to reduce the number of samples sent i.e. decimate(what I think of) and after decimation by factor 4, I will have 1000Hz samples and then I can interpolate back to 4000Hz.
I am collecting 32 samples 125 times in a sec which makes it 4000Hz

I studied basic decimation and interpolation from [here](https://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/decimation/) among other references and am using CMSIS FIR Decimator and FIR Interpolator.

I set parameters as following looking at CMSIS [decimator](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__FIR__decimate.html#ga3b01ec9df00d759f79c934b239cead73) and [interpolator](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__FIR__Interpolate.html#ga026a02cda40616476e33b82e4eaf855d)

```
number of coefficients in the filter: 4
decimation factor: 4
filter coefficients: [1, 0, 0, 0]
number of input samples to process per call: 32
```

```
upsample factor: 4
number of filter coefficients in the filter: 4
filter coefficient buffer: [1, 0, 0, 0]
number of samples to process: 8
```

Filter coefficients are stored as {0,0,0,1} in variable i.e. time reverse order as in documentation [here](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__FIR__decimate.html#ga3b01ec9df00d759f79c934b239cead73).

Is my understanding of FIR filter coefficient correct i.e. [1, 0, 0, 0] since I want to simply decimate and not actually filter the data?

I am getting values as [0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1] etc. after implementing decimator which is incorrect. What mistake am I making here? Any reference I need to go through?

Answer (score 0):

No. [1, 0, 0, 0] is not correct. It is something like delta function with len=4
If you use these coefficients for filtering, aliasing will occur.

Before downsampling, you need a filter. if you want to decrease the noise level 60 or 80 dB you need more coefficients like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e62u8b7n1f92gnr/CoeffForDownsample2.txt?dl=0). So you should design a suitable filter.  If you have a computational problem for 64 coeffs, you can use a CIC filter.
For more information about CIC or Filter designing, you can see [chapter 10](http://www.elcom-hu.com/Electrical/Digital%20Singnal%20Proccessing/4th/4th%20Digital%20Signal%20Processing%20-%20Proakis%20and%20Manolakis.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs and references. I will go through the doc you shared and implement the same.

Comment: You're welcome. To design a suitable filter you can use "fdatool" in Matlab.